# How to get instances of ckeditor with ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ckeditor4.x

I am trying to use ckeditor with angularjs I have added a directive for the same. It is working fine. The problem is when I try to get the instances list of the ckeditor.

// directive

```
app.directive('ckeditor', function () {
     return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
            var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(element[0]);
            if(!ngModel)return;
            ck.on('pasteState', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                });
            });
            ngModel.$render = function (value) {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

// ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="key in []| range:0:(vm.listCount-1)"> 
     <textarea ckeditor id="content_{{key + 1}}"
               ng-model="vm.contentList[key].content">
     </textarea>
</div>
```

In controller I am trying to get instances list. There instead of 
content_0,content_1 etc. I am getting content_{{key + 1}} only one instance

```
console.log(CKEDITOR.instances);
```

I want to get the proper instance of the ckeditor but I am getting only one value that is content_{{key + 1}} Please someone suggest.

Comment: Does it work with `ng-repeat="key in [0,1]"`? How does the controller initialize `vm.contentList`? What is the code for the `range` filter? What error messages do you get in the Developer Console?

Comment: vm.contentList is empty initially based on the range it will add values dynamically. There is no error message. Range filter is based on the dropdown where count will be available eg: 1, 2, 3

Comment: my concern is instead of content_0,content_1  it will log instanse Id as content_{{key + 1}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the directive needs to set the `id` attribute before invoking `CKEDITOR.replace`:

```
app.directive('ckeditor', function () {
     return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
            //COMPUTE id attribute
            if (attr.key) {
                var keyValue = scope.$eval(attr.key);
                element[0].id += "_"+keyValue;
            };
            var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(element[0]);
            if(!ngModel)return;
            ck.on('pasteState', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                });
            });
            ngModel.$render = function (value) {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
<div ng-repeat="key in [0,1]"> 
     <textarea ckeditor key="$index+1" id="content"
               ng-model="vm.contentList[key].content">
     </textarea>
</div>
```

The CKEDITOR is likely instantiating the editor before the AngularJS framework computes `id="content_{{key + 1}}"`.

Comment: If I console.log(attr.id); it shows the proper value but  in 
 controller console.log(CKEDITOR.instances); it is not showing me the same.

Comment: I  also think that before Angular js computes ckeditor is getting initiated. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: `attr.id` is not the same as `element[0].id`.

Comment: after console.log element[0].id   --  content_{{key + 1}} this is what  it is printing in console

Comment: That is working If I follow the example which you shared thanks